# How to extract data from .txt file with unspecific header

Tags: python-2.7

I have a .txt files which consists the data from multiple .txt file. It start with the filename then header(no. of headers are varies) and data. Examples are here. Anyone have any ideas to do this?

IMPORTANT: I need to leave a "-" when one of the students do not have the subject.

input.txt

```
Student 1.txt 
Maths,90
Science,50
English,62
Student 2.txt
Maths,75
Science,80
Chinese,88
Student 3.txt
Maths,83
Chinese,22
English,90
Physics,56
```

Now I have the code below to make it into dict

```
open_input_file=open("input.txt","r")
datalines= open_input_file.readlines()
open_input_file.readlines()
open_input_file.close()
line=[]
value=0
from collections import defaultdict
d1=defaultdict(list)
for line in datalines:
        if line.find(',')>-1:
            key=line.split(",")[0]
            value=line.split(",")[1].strip("\n")
            d1[key].append(value)
        else:
            key="filename"
            value=line
            d1[key].append(value)

d=dict((key,tuple(value)) for key, value in d1.iteritems())
print d
```

and I get this

```
{'Chinese': ('88', '22'), 'Science': ('50', '80'), 'filename': ('Student 1.1\n', 'Student 2.1\n', 'Student 3.1\n'), 'English': ('62', '90'), 'Maths': ('90', '75', '83'), 'Physics': ('56',)}
```

but what I really want is something like this, so that the mark is correspond to the student number

```
filename,Student 1.txt, Student 2.txt, Student 3.txt    
Maths,90,75,83
Science,50,80,-
English,62,-,90
Chinese,-,88,22
Physics,-,-,-,56
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? You can read the input file and split it based on the known structure - like the keyword Student.. Probably good to make some sort of a dictionary for all the subjects.

Comment: @atru i tried to compare line by line using .split, but the output is not desired. Let me try with the dictionary method that u mentioned.

Comment: Try and post it in your question, even just the part where you read the file and split it into pieces. It will make others more willing to help. Also, have a look at [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @atru thank you for the helpful tips! I had updated the questions. Do you have any idea what to improve for my code to get the desired output?

Comment: `input` is a python's keyword, you should not use it as a variable name. Also you do not mention how you retrieve your data, this is missing from your script. I cannot get the result you mention with your script.

Comment: Also, do you know from the start what subjects may be listed, or must the script guess all possible subjects?

Comment: @zezollo I had edited the question with the complete code. I do not know from the start for the subject list. The script has to guess all possible subject.

Comment: OK, and what if a student hadn't studied anything? Ignore him, or return a list of `'-'`, or can't this case happen?

Comment: @zezollo This case will not happen. No data will be shown in the input.txt if the student hadn't studied anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can probably be improved, but it keeps most of the original script and makes it complete:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d1 = defaultdict(list)

open_input_file = open("input.txt", "r")
datalines = open_input_file.readlines()
open_input_file.readlines()
open_input_file.close()

# This part will gather all possible subjects in a set
subjects = set()
for line in datalines:
    if "," in line:
        subjects.add(line.split(",")[0])

# Now let's browse the data
student_subjects = set()
for line in datalines:
    if "," in line:  # new subject
        subject = line.split(",")[0]
        value = line.split(",")[1].strip("\n")
        d1[subject].append(value)
        student_subjects.add(subject)
    else:  # new student
        d1["filename"].append(line.strip("\n"))
        # But before starting to handle the new student's subjects, let's
        # complete the missing ones from previous student.
        if student_subjects:  # true if at least one student has been processed
            for subject in subjects - student_subjects:  # missing subjects
                d1[subject].append('-')
        student_subjects = set()

# Same thing when we meet the end of data (if there were missing subjects
# for the last student, like Science in this example data)
if student_subjects:
    for s in subjects - student_subjects:
        d1[s].append('-')

d = dict((key, tuple(value)) for key, value in d1.iteritems())

print d

# to view all this better:
print 'filenames: {}'.format(d['filename'])
for subject in d:
    if subject != 'filename':
        print '{}: {}'.format(subject, d[subject])
```

Output:

```
{'Chinese': ('-', '88', '22'), 'Science': ('50', '80', '-'), 'filename': ('Student 1.txt\n', 'Student 2.txt\n', 'Student 3.txt\n'), 'English': ('62', '-', '90'), 'Maths': ('90', '75', '83'), 'Physics': ('-', '-', '56')}
filenames: ('Student 1.txt', 'Student 2.txt', 'Student 3.txt')
Chinese: ('-', '88', '22')
Science: ('50', '80', '-')
English: ('62', '-', '90')
Maths: ('90', '75', '83')
Physics: ('-', '-', '56')
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want! Thanks a lot for this. It troubles me for a few days to figure out the algorithm.

Comment: Glad it helped! You may upvote the answer if it is helpful and clear enough.